# Proper way to install latest version of Python on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, python

I'm trying to set up a Python development environment on Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to install the latest version of Python 2 (2.7.11) alongside the OS version so I followed the instructions here: [How to use Latest Python 2.7.x “The Right Way” on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://superuser.com/questions/602587/how-to-use-latest-python-2-7-x-the-right-way-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) The basic steps were:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

I thought this would install a second copy *in addition* to the default 2.7.6 (like how Hombrew works in MacOS), but now when I run `python --version` I get `2.7.11`. `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`, same for `which python2.7`. Nothing is visibly broken in the OS but I was hoping to avoid this sort of collision. Is there a better way of doing this?

**UPDATE**: I see now that in the release notes it says "KEEP IN MIND that this PPA will replace a core system component (i.e. Python 2.7)!" I guess that is by design, but I am still wondering if there's a less disruptive way of installing the latest Python 2.7 via package manager.

Answer (score 1):

## Warning!

#### Below is only to upgrade Python2 to the latest version!

**The below process should not be used to install Python3 as Python3 is incompatible with Python2 and things *will* break** (if you're not very, very careful)

**Installing Dependencies:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

**Downloading Python:**

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/Python-2.7.12.tgz
```

**Extracting archive:**

```
tar -xvf Python-2.7.12.tgz
cd Python-2.7.12
```

**Build and install:**

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: Already upvoted, but I would add a warning that installing python 3 _and_ removing python 2 is dangerous...

Comment: No no no, we are not removing python 2

Comment: I know, you know but the next person googling "python install Ubuntu" will now get your answer, so I would still add a warning...  **;-)**

Comment: voted your comment for that.

Comment: _That's what I meant!_  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

There are some instructions on doing this [here](http://mbless.de/blog/2016/01/09/upgrade-to-python-2711-on-ubuntu-1404-lts.html). It suggests compiling python 2.7.11 from the source and creating a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) in which to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.If possible I'd prefer to use a package manager, but this sounds like a good alternative if that doesn't work.

Comment: Please quote the most relevant parts of the links, do not rely on external sites! [answer]